# Is there a way to get Visual Studio to run "Transform All Templates" upon a successful build?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, build-process, t4

I have a T4 template that geneates helpert code based on other code that is declared within my project.  Because of this, I have to build my project before I run "Transform All Templates".  Is it possible to have "Transform All Templates" run as a post-build-event upon a successful build?

Answer (score 2):

I've not really tried it myself but I think you want to look into [this](http://www.olegsych.com/2010/04/understanding-t4-msbuild-integration/). You should be able to modify your project files to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2):

An easier solution may be to modify your templates A LA the [T4 MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) templates so that they automatically mark themselves as dirty on build (check the docs page and search for AlwaysKeepTemplateDirty for details).  You could probably edit your templates to have them do the same thing.