# How to get Visual Studio to transform specific T4 Templates on build?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, t4

Is it possible to get Visual Studio to build only a specific set of T4 Templates on build?

Currently I use the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3381556/8973497) to make Visual Studio transform *all* of my T4 Template files upon build. However, I have a T4 Template that runs into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14409368/8973497) when it is transformed during build time. Therefore, I want to transform all templates *except* this particular one.

More specifically, I have the following code in my `.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <TransformOnBuild>true</TransformOnBuild>
    <TransformOutOfDateOnly>false</TransformOutOfDateOnly>
    <OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>true</OverwriteReadOnlyOutputFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

which "works" to rebuild most of my T4 Templates the way I want.

However, I have a T4 Template included in that `.csproj` that makes use of the `Host` variable in such a way that it causes the transformation to fail during build time (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14409896/8973497)).

It is necessary that all of the templates except the latter are transformed upon build, so is there any way I can achieve this behavior?

*Note: This type of `<PropertyGroup>` is used across multiple projects in multiple solutions, so for the sake of keeping things the same across the board I would prefer to continue using this for my transformations, if at all possible.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to the  metadata item for the template you don't want to transform as follows:

```
<Content Include="TextTemplate2.tt" >
  <Generator Condition="$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)=='true'">TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>TextTemplate2.txt</LastGenOutput>
</Content>
```

This will stop the *Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets* from recognising the file as one that needs to be transformed, except when building inside Visual Studio.